# split_part multiple delimeters

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to use split_part on multiple delimiters?
So for `lower(trim(split_part(t.advisor_last_name,' ',1))` I would like to split `advisor_last_name` if either space (as shows) or comma exist. We basically have alot of CPA, CFA, CIMA etc. that don't allow me to do proper matching between different files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [REGEX_REPLACE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) to replace every other delimiter to ' '(whitespace character) and then do split_part for ' '! Seems like a workaround.

You could have done it directly if the delimiter parameter for split_part could be a regular expression but it doesn't seem like it is.

Comment: Do you mind showing how can I implement regex to replace every other delimiter to ' '?

Comment: For now Ill do regular replace for ';'

Comment: `regex_replace(source_string,"[\!;,.]",' ')`

You can insert more punctuations you want in the regex pattern but make sure to escape characters if needed. This way anything within the [ ] (character class) will be replaced with the third parameter which is ' ' in your case

Comment: Ah amazing. `select regexp_replace(advisor_last_name,'[\!;,.]',' ')` worked like a charm